# Smallest positive integer $n$ such that $S_n$ has an element of order $2n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

The Problem:

> - Find the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $S_n$  has an element of order greater than $2n$
> - Let $n$ be an even positive integer. Prove that $A_n$ had an element of order greater than $2n$ if and only if $n\ge 14$

I know that a permutation can be written as a product of disjoint cycles and the order of the LCM of the lengths of these cycles is the order of that permutation. Also if you write a permutation as a product of its disjoint cycles considering the invariant elements to be $1$-cycles, then the lengths of the disjoint cycles, $\{n_1,n_2,\cdots,n_k\}$, constitute a partition of the integer $n$. Then we need to find out the least integer $n$ such that the LCM of $n_1,n_2,\cdots,n_k$ for some partition of $n$ is $\ge 2n$.

I don't know what to do next? Please help.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. But it's hard to be satisfied with hit and trial. How should I go about it rigorously?

Comment: $(1,2,3,4)(5,6,7,8,9) $ for $n=10$?

Comment: And there user87.... proves me wrong: $\;n\;$ can be even!

Comment: In the first part, do you mean exactly $2 n$ or *at least* $2 n$?

Comment: At least $2n$. I am editing the question likewise.

Comment: Also, in the second part, did you mean greater or greater than or equal to?

Comment: Oops sorry, both is greater than. But I would be happy to know how to approach it either way.

Comment: See also: [Element of order $2n$ in symmetric group $S_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/408563)

Answer (score 1):

To answer the first question: (1,2,3,4)(5,6,7,8,9) for n=9 appears to be the smallest n.

A counter example to the second statement is provided by the even permutation (1,2,3)(4,5,6,7,8,9,10) for n=10.

Comment: So there is no way other than hit and trial